# ADFS vs LDAP bind in the Cloud

Tags: ldap, adfs

Why would it be more desirable, (i.e. lower cost) to integrate with a party's AD via ADFS instead of LDAP bind when in the Cloud?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are two completely different scenarios.

Using ADFS is not using cloud LDAP.

There's a whole extra layer for the WS-Federation protocol with all kinds of certificate constraints etc.

Plus you need a server to host it.

(Connecting to your LDAP from the cloud might mean punching holes in your firewall.)

Comment: Thank you. That is very helpful. I'm sorry I can't upvote this respond but I don't have enough points.

Answer (score 0):

Integrating with ADFS over LDAP bind provides the following benefits

1. Externalized authentication that helps the app focus on the business logic
2. Policy based controls for authentication based on whether access is happening from inside or outside the corporate network
3. Integration with multiple MFA providers such as Azure MFA, RSA, Safenet, Gemalto, Vasco...
4. Per-app policy based controls to invoke MFA based on user, location & device
5. Per-app policy based controls to gate access to the application based on user, location, device & strength of authentication
6. Easier ability to have authentication work from inside or outside the network as it is a standard pattern
7. Monitoring & usage analytics support with Azure AD Connect Health & SCOM.

Hope that helps. 
Thanks //Sam

Comment: Thank you! This is extremely helpful. I'm sorry I can't upvote this response but I am told I don't have enough points yet.